# How can I check whether someone is friend of another one in Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I know that the endpoint `me/friends` lists user friends which also authorized the app. Another sub-endpoint exists: `me/friends/<user>`, which checks whether two users are friends:

> Modifiers
>
> You can append another person's id to the edge in order to determine whether that person is friends with the root node user:
>
> [...]
>
> If user-a is friends with user-b in the above request, the response will contain the User object for user-b. If they are not friends, it will return an empty dataset.

Does this modifier also imply both users have authorized the application? Or will it return data for any specified friend?

Currently I'm the only developer of an application, which is in test mode. In my Graph API call I get every picture (from the 'me' user) and their tags. From each tag (which has `id` and `name` of the tagged user), I want to know whether such user (by id in the tag) is a friend of the current ('me') user.

But the result is `{data:[], summary:xxx}` where summary is my friend count (as if I asked the `me/friends` endpoint, without specifying another user).

**Notes**: I am the only user of the app. I am the administrator of the app. I granted the `user_friends` permission.

**Question**: Is this behavior expected for `me/friends/<user>`? I know it is expected for `me/friends` since nobody is playing in the app yet. By "expected behavior" I mean: such sub-endpoint returns data ONLY if the user is my friend AND authorized the app. Is there a way to check whether two given users are friends regardless whether the second one authorized the app or not?